# How to fix npm start throwing error in React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to make my first React app, everything is smooth until I run `npm start`, then it throws this error:

```
C:\Users\hp\Desktop\react-projects\my-app> npm start

> my-app@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

node:internal/fs/utils:344
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp; C:'
    at Object.realpathSync (node:fs:2490:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\react-projects\my-app\node_modules\temp-dir\index.js:9:13)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\Desktop\react-projects\my-app\node_modules\tempy\index.js:5:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14) {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'lstat',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp; C:'
```

I've tried:

- Deleting the entire app folder and running `npx create-react-app my-app` all over again.
- `npx create-react-app@latest my-app`
- deleting `package.json` and running `npm init` again, then adding script.

So far nothing seems to fix it.

Comment: The `path` seems suspicious, `Temp; C:`? Something seems to be broken in your Node install or Windows environment, not this specific app.

Comment: Yea, I noticed the path was weird, so after u mentioned it, I removed the c at the end of the path, deleted the my-app folder and ran the whole npx create-react-app again, when I ran npm start this time, it worked, thanks a bunch.